# port 22 ,Network is unreachable

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 I'm working on server in where my client website is hosted. I was able to connect but now when I try to connect via ssh or filezilla I get this message:

> ssh: connect to host home67635****.1and1-data.host port 22: Network is unreachable

I can connect from another computer but not mine.

On the other hand I can connect also to others servers from my computer.

Is that means my IP address is blocked or what ?

Comment: Possible related to [ssh gives message "Ubuntu Forums Thread: Network is unreachable"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1529943)

Answer (score 1):

Try to connect to another server from your computer that gives this problem. Probably, your network is under a firewall with some blocking rules.